# cannot paste my metadata keychain password

Tags: keychain

I am following the steps in [How do I stop 'mdwrite wants to use the "metadata" keychain' prompts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310450/how-do-i-stop-mdwrite-wants-to-use-the-metadata-keychain-prompts)

But having a problem, I am unable to type the crazy password into the system dialog that comes up, and copy-paste does not work. Because it is stealing the input focus, I cannot do much else. I had to manually type the password. Is this a Mac Bug? Or am I just doing it all incorrectly.

(Mac Mini on Catalina, while editing xcode project options/targets after locking keychain) Otherwise pretty much exactly as in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Clear the input field of the "mdwrite wants to ..." pop-up

Get the "metadata" login password

Put your cursor in the input field of the pop-up

Go to the menu and under "Edit", go down and click "Paste".

Worked for me, because right-clicking while the mouse was *in* the field had the usual editing pop-up come up *behind* the "mdwrite ..." pop-up.

I'd never seen that before, but some pop-ups must have a higher priority than others ...

Comment: Thanks, yes the issue is that I'm not a regular mac user, so anything that requires keyboard gymnastics still throws me off until I try again or persevere :-).